# Layout pre-render modification in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-modules

I'm having a hard time figuring out how it would be possible to call functions on a layout in ZF2 before it gets delivered. More specifically I have certain elements that need to be changed in both in the layout and the views. Also this needs to be done in every module inside the actions so I can set said elements.

This is basically supposed to be a rendering engine. And I can't switch to something else like Twig or the built in engine.

Comment: You might want to get a bit more specific and maybe provide an example & further constraints. "Calling functions" might me viewhelpers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean by "delivered" and by changing "elements". However, As Zend\View is event driven, I think that you should probably register your own listener on `Zend\Mvc\Application`'s *render* event. Give it a priority of greater than 1 and your listener's callback will be triggered before rendering happens. If you want to alter the HTML after the layout had rendered, then register your listener with a negative priority, so that it runs after rendering.